# Routing doesn't work in case of 'autoconnect' network manager connections

Tags: wireless-router, routing, wireless-access-point, networkmanager

I have a computer with wifi adapter (interface `wlp3s0`) which can work in access point mode.

Using `network-manager` I've created wifi access point with static addresses:

```
nmcli c a type wifi ifname wlp3s0 con-name 'hotspot' autoconnect no ssid 'test'
nmcli c m 'hotspot' 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method static ipv4.addresses '192.168.3.1'
nmcli c m 'hotspot' wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli c m 'hotspot' wifi-sec.psk '12345678'
nmcli c m 'hotspot' ipv4.gateway '192.168.3.1'
nmcli c m 'hotspot' ipv4.routes '192.168.3.0/24 192.168.3.1'
nmcli c up 'hotspot'
```

It works well until I manually enable and disable connection using `nmcli c up`/`nmcli c down` - access point appears, I can connect to it.

When I enable `autoconnect` access points appears and I can connect to it, however there is no manual-defined route `192.168.3.0/24 192.168.3.1` and I can't connect to ssh server running on this computer or do anything related with IP communication.

Why route defined in connection doesn't work in case of `autoconnect`?

UPD: my connections settings:

```
$ nmcli c s hotspot
connection.id:                          hotspot
connection.uuid:                        3ecf0211-bd69-4a31-880c-24793bc1bc83
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.interface-name:              wlp3s0
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.timestamp:                   1561903483
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   test
802-11-wireless.mode:                   ap
802-11-wireless.band:                   bg
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            AC:FD:CE:99:9D:78
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              default (0)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      --
802-11-wireless-security.proto:
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:
802-11-wireless-security.group:
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  0 (unknown)
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (none)
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:
ipv4.dns-search:
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.3.1/32
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            { ip = 192.168.3.0/24, nh = 192.168.3.1 }
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:
ipv6.dns-search:
ipv6.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           hotspot
GENERAL.UUID:                           3ecf0211-bd69-4a31-880c-24793bc1bc83
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        wlp3s0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/7
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.3.1/32
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::227e:56d:e216:26d3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

Comment: Why are you using the device's own address as the gateway? Where are the packets supposed to be routed -- should they go in a loop forever?

Comment: Yes, it seems I've copy pasted it from some instructions found in the internet and forget to remove this line when created topic. There is no gateway in my actual connection. I've added actual settings of my connection to the post.

Comment: There is. You might not have a gateway for 0.0.0.0/0, but you are still specifying 192.168.3.1 as the gateway for 192.168.3.0/24. What is that supposed to mean? (It seems like a long-winded, BSDish way of saying that ipv4.address is 192.168.3.1/24?)

Comment: Yes, I don't have default for 0.0.0.0/0. Well, it seems, I don't know how routing table should look in this case. I thought that `ipv4.routes '192.168.3.0/24 192.168.3.1'` means send all packets going to the `192.168.3.0/24` network to the interface with `192.168.3.1` address.

Comment: Not quite: to the interface _and_ to the device having that address. (Otherwise it would be impossible to have multiple routers...) And yes, from your description, you're indeed trying to do by hand what `ipv4.address=192.168.3.1/24` would have done for you automatically (on pretty much any OS – it's literally just the "subnet mask").

Comment: Yep, it seems you are right, I've removed manual route, set `ipv4.address=192.168.3.1/24` and it works... until you `down`/`up` connection manually. When `autoconnect` is enabled for connection there are no routes for `192.168.3.1/24` network, unfortunately. So main problem of the topic remains.